# Cannot run Fortify with multi CPU for a C++ project

Tags: c++, fortify

I have a C++ project setup with CMake, running on Mac. Recently I am looking into adding Fortify to do auto code analyzation. I am using Fortify version 22.1.

After set up the CMake and shell scripts, I found that if I compile with more than one CPU (using -j), the compiler (c++ or g++) will have issues generating the libs. Sometimes it will pass and successfully generate the Fortify output, but others it will just error out. Multi CPUs compile fine for this project without running Fortify.

I also see this error when I compile with Fortify (no matter it success or not):

```
[error]: Translator execution failed.  Please consult the Troubleshooting section of the User Manual. 
Translator returned status 1:

error: unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in ''
```

This error always happens after a "Linking CXX xxxxx xxxx". I can't find any documentation about them.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you.

**Update more details about my setup:**

I use shell files to wrap the sourceanalyzer like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec sourceanalyzer -b MyApp /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ "$@"
```

And my CMake setup like this:

```
if (${ENABLE_FORTIFY} EQUAL 1)
    set(CMAKE_CC_COMPILER ${AVSxAppDALDefaultImplementation_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/fortify-build-cc.sh)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${AVSxAppDALDefaultImplementation_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/fortify-build-cxx.sh)
endif()
```

My shell script to run CMake and then to the scan:

```
cmake $PACKAGEPATH \
    ...    
    -DENABLE_FORTIFY="${ENABLE_FORTIFY}"

echo "---BUILDING---"
make release

if [[ $ENABLE_FORTIFY == 1 ]]; then
    echo "---RUNNING FORTIFY SCAN---"
    sourceanalyzer -b ${CURRENT_PROJECT_NAME} -scan -f fortify_scan_result_${CURRENT_PROJECT_NAME}.txt
fi
```

Comment: If `make -j` fails it could be because of dependency problems. And the error message you get could be because of misconfiguration of Fortify, or you use it in the wrong way. Is it possible for you to create a [mre] of your build configuration, and show it to us?

Comment: Where can I put the example codes?

Comment: If you need to improve your question, then [edit] it.

Comment: Updated with my cmake and shell scripts